# Test type of value in list during list comprehension BEFORE iterating on value?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I have a list that looks like this:

```
test = [[1,11],[2,22],3.0]
```

and I want to create a list of the first value in each pair from it like this:

```
[f for [f,l] in test]
```

so that I get this result:

```
[1,2]
```

but, as expected, I get this error:

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

So I tried to modify it like this:

```
[f for [f,l] in test if type([f,l]) != float]
```

and I still get the same error:

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

How do I test the type of the value in the list inside the list comprehension *before* it iterates over the items inside?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do the unpacking quite so early in this case since you need the full item in order to check it's type.

```
>>> test = [[1,11],[2,22],3.0]
>>> [item[0] for item in test if isinstance(item, list)]
[1, 2]
```

The way that you were doing it (`for a, b in iterable`) tries the unpacking before you have a chance to look at the type so you can end up with `TypeError` before you have a chance to look at the items.

If you really like the unpacking as you go, you can filter the test itesm first and then write your list comprehension on the filtered data...

```
>>> test_iterables = (item for item in test if isinstance(item, list))
>>> [f for f, l in test_iterables]
```

---

<sup>Also note that depending on what types you want to support, it might be better to do 
`isinstance(item, collections.Sequence)` or `isinstance(item, collections.Iterable)`</sup>

Comment: Ignore my now-deleted comment: it was an unrelated issue. This works.

Answer (score 2):

```
test = [[1,11],[2,22],3.0]

print([f for [f,l] in filter(lambda x: type(x) is list, test)])
```

> [1, 2]

Answer (score 0):

Your unpacking does not work because your list contains non matching types. 
You can simply filter on `hasattr` given that only your lists (in this case) will have the attribute `__len__` and index the first item of the list:

```
>>> test = [[1,11],[2,22],3.0]
>>> [i[0] for i in test if hasattr(i, '__len__')]
[1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a simple approach like this:

```
test = [[1,11],[2,22],3.0]

test_copy = test[:]

for num in test:
    if type(num) != list:
        test_copy.remove(num)
else:
    print([num[0] for num in test_copy])
```

Output:

```
[1, 2]
```

You can also replace the last line with this if you want to:

```
print(list(map(lambda x: x[0], test_copy)))
```